# Ubuntu 16.10 can't get anything to work not Steam, nor Plex, and not updates

Tags: updates, steam, plex

Steam wont start, `plex` doesn't install and the updates make an `389 admin error`.

I'm not a Ubuntu savvy, yet, have had it less then a year so I don't understand it all. But have been reading Internet for many hours and still cant figure it out, how to make it work.

Nope <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>v</kbd> didn't work.

Heres the message:

```
~$ /var/log/apache2/error.log and journalctl -xnbash: /var/log/apache2/error.log: Åtkomst nekas"
```

And for Steam:

```
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
/bin/bash: /home/mamma/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /bin/bash)
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1476379980)
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

'apt-cache radeon search' resulted in:
apt-cache search radeon: kommandot hittades inte (no such command)

lspci -nn | grep VGA: kommandot hittades inte command (no such command)

xserver-xorg-video-ati is already the newest version (1:7.7.1-1).
bash: syntaxfel nära den oväntade symbolen "("
Fel uppstod vid hantering:
 389-admin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

About the apche log: (when i press shift+ctrl+v i get adblock blackables in my window?)
mamma@mamma-System-Product-Name:~$ journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at tor 2016-12-08 12:41:21 CET, end at lör 2016-12-10 19:07:03 CET
dec 10 19:07:03 mamma-System-Product-Name NetworkManager[868]:   [14813932
dec 10 19:07:03 mamma-System-Product-Name NetworkManager[868]:   [14813932
dec 10 19:07:03 mamma-System-Product-Name NetworkManager[868]:   [14813932
dec 10 19:07:03 mamma-System-Product-Name dbus[800]: [system] Activating via sys
dec 10 19:07:03 mamma-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager S
-- Subject: Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd

### -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

-- Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has begun starting up.
dec 10 19:07:03 mamma-System-Product-Name dbus[800]: [system] Successfully activ
dec 10 19:07:03 mamma-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Sc
-- Subject: Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd

### -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

### -- Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has finished starting up.

-- The start-up result is done.
dec 10 19:07:03 mamma-System-Product-Name nm-dispatcher[8910]: req:1 'dhcp4-chan
dec 10 19:07:03 mamma-System-Product-Name nm-dispatcher[8910]: req:1 'dhcp4-chan
dec 10 19:07:03 mamma-System-Product-Name dhclient[346]: bound to 
192.168.1.136

dirsrv-admin.service - 389 Administration Server.
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dirsrv-admin.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since sön 2016-12-11 12:32:43 CET; 6ms ago
  Process: 16983 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start -f /etc/dirsrv/admin-serv/httpd.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Comment: You might want to put each matter in an own question , AND provide a bit more input what you tried and what not and where you're stuck. In the current state your question is in it is to broad for this sites format to answer.

Comment: Ok, dont know how to make a log yet.
But tried to update in terminal and get 
"Failed to start 389 Adm..." and
"Process: 31198 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start -f /etc/dirsrv/admin-serv/httpd.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)" and
"Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since fre 2016-12-09 13:15:00 CET; 8ms ago"
Steam doesnt even start so no log no nothing, and Plex we can put on the side for now.

Comment: As first you can [edit] your question to include the information, no need to put it into comments. As it is for steam, open a terminal and type `steam` and check what it is printing out there. (***Hint:*** you can copy and paste from terminal with shift+ctrl+c for copying and shift+ctrl+v for paste). Your Apache does not seem to start up, looks you have miss-configured it, check the apache logs in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and `journalctl -xn`.

Comment: Well, to see the apache logs you need to output them o.k. here is the full line for that `cat /var/log/apache2/error.log` then another command to see maybe what has went wrong was `journalctl -xn`. And copy and pasting works like described, of course you need to select the text to copy beforehand with your mouse. Still, please open up a question for each matter alone.

Comment: Ok will do that then.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably reinstall video drivers that you have, or install video drivers. If you run 'apt-cache search radeon' you will see many xorg drivers available, go ahead and install the apropriate one.

You can see the current one installed, if there is one, by running 'dpkg -l | grep xorg'

All the information available at this link is too much to post, but there is a great Ubuntu tutorial on identifying the graphics card you have, and links to instructions on installing graphics drivers here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

---

#### Installing Radeon graphics drivers

- I am going off of the assumption that running this command 'lspci -nn | grep VGA' shows 'Sapphire Radeon HD 7850' while going through the link above. This cars uses the PITCAIRN chipset, part of the Radeon HD 7800 series. These are supported by this driver for Ubuntu 16.04 and 14.04.

  If you have tried this, or any other video driver install before, but failed, please see this page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/VideoDriverDetection#Problem:_Need_to_purge_-fglrx to learn how to purge the old video driver out of your system.

  To install the driver for your card, simply run 'sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati'

dirsrv-admin.service - 389 Administration Server.
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dirsrv-admin.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since sön 2016-12-11 12:32:43 CET; 6ms ago
  Process: 16983 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start -f /etc/dirsrv/admin-serv/httpd.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the entire conversation taking place here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49982/discussion-on-answer-by-kyle-h-ubuntu-16-10-cant-get-anything-to-work-not-steam).

Comment: Thank you couldnt use chat because i had to littele rep. ;-)