# Apache error (admin389)

Tags: package-management, apache2

What do i do about it. made a 16.10 (yakkety) install??

```
[Sat Dec 10 20:07:39.025423 2016] [core:warn] [pid 10236] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} is not defined
[Sat Dec 10 20:07:39.025470 2016] [core:warn] [pid 10236] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined
[Sat Dec 10 20:07:39.025490 2016] [core:warn] [pid 10236] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_USER} is not defined
[Sat Dec 10 20:07:39.025497 2016] [core:warn] [pid 10236] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined
[Sat Dec 10 20:07:39.025507 2016] [core:warn] [pid 10236] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Sat Dec 10 20:07:39.027599 2016] [core:warn] [pid 10236:tid 140045921779200] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Sat Dec 10 20:07:39.027739 2016] [core:warn] [pid 10236:tid 140045921779200] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Sat Dec 10 20:07:39.027750 2016] [core:warn] [pid 10236:tid 140045921779200] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
AH00526: Syntax error on line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}
```

The problem is i cant update for the nst of the time , i cant get steam to work and a lot of the commands in the terminal dont work.

```
xserver-xorg-video-ati is already the newest version (1:7.7.1-1).
bash: syntaxfel nära den oväntade symbolen "(" Fel uppstod vid hantering: 389-admin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What's on line 74 of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`? And what command did you run, that caused this error?

Comment: I ran Apache2
I dont know what you mean on line 74?

Comment: The second to last line, starts "AH00526", refers to a `syntax error on line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. Open that file, and have a look at line 74. If you started Apache from a terminal, like Gnome-terminal, you can read (and edit) this file with `sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: # Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

Comment: Which command *exactly* resulted in the Apt/dpkg error in your question? Could you please include its *full, verbatim* output in your question? Also, you can make most programs print English messages by prefixing the command with `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX`, e. g. `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX free`. Works the same for graphical applications. With super-user privileges you need `sudo LC_MESSAGES=POSIX apt ...` or `gksudo env LC_MESSAGES=POSIX synaptic` (for graphical applications).

Comment: My apache error was resolved here.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/858770/ubuntu-16-10-cant-get-anything-to-work-not-steam-nor-plex-and-not-updates?noredirect=1#comment1325735_858770
But the posts has been deleted/moved.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu (and generally on any operating system derived from Debian) you do not normally run Apache HTTP server directly, but rather you must use `apache2ctl`. The error messages in your question indicate that you have tried to run it directly; you *can* do this, but then you must mimic the actions of `apache2ctl`, in particular you must set the expected environment variables.

Comment: I dont even understand what you say :-)?? Because i havent done anything else than try to install steam and trying to update with the latest drivers from yakkety.